# how to restore backslash symbol's shape in R

Tags: r, rstudio, backslash

I am R user and after running some R code written by a Chinese programmer, my Rstudio shows the backslash symbol's shape as ¥. How can I restore original backslash symbol \ in Rstudio?

Comment: Please provide details what you did. Where does the error occur? Do you import data?

Comment: Maybe `RStudio -> File -> Reopen with Encoding...` helps you.